# Prove by smallest counterexample $3 | (5^n - 2^n)$

Tags: proof-writing, induction

I have it up to here:

For $k - 1$ (which is true) $3 | (5^{k-1} - 2^{k-1})$

$5^k - 2^k = 3n$, where $n\in Z$

So $5(5^{k-1}) - 2(2^{k-1})$

But now what? Is there some algebra trick I'm missing because I am stuck here

Comment: Smallest counterexample is a variant on induction, it's not quite that simple

Comment: Do you have to use that particular method of proof? Seems a lot more straightforward to use modular arithmetic.

Comment: What you mean is usually called infinite descent.  You assume there is an $n$ that fails and show that there must be a smaller value that fails as well.  You then say there must be a minimum value that fails, but note that $0$ does not.  Your last expression is not a complete sentence.  What is it trying to prove?

Answer (score 1):

What you should be saying is assume there is an $n$ such that $3 \not \mid 5^n-2^n$  Based on that assumption, show that $3 \not \mid 5^{n-1}-2^{n-1}$ and the failure continues.  It would force $3 \not \mid 5^1-2^1$, which is false.  This means the original assumption is wrong and $3 \mid 5^n-2^n$ for all $n$

Answer (score 1):

Let $k$ be the smallest positive integer for which $3\not|~5^k - 2^k$. Of course $k\neq 1$, so $k-1$ is a positive integer, therefore

$$3~|~5^{k-1} - 2^{k-1}$$

so

$$3~|~2(5^{k-1} - 2^{k-1}) + 3\cdot 5^{k-1} = 5^k - 2^k$$

which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Hint::

$n\ge 1$;

Consider the binomial expansion of

$5^n=(3+2)^n; $

All terms except the last term $2^n$ have a factor $3$.

What can you say about $5^n-2^n$ ?